# How to put choice value using aspose.cell?

Tags: .net, aspose-cells

I am using Aspose. Cell for .net to write some data into Excel. I have a quick question:

how to insert such kind of value?

[image]

I find that there is a method "`cell.putvalue(string)`" , is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If it is List data validation applied in the worksheet cell, then you may simply try to use: `Cell.PutValue(stringvalue)` to insert the value into the cell.
2. If it is ComboBox ActiveX control, you may try like following:

```cs
//Access first shape in the sheet as combo box control, and set its value property
Aspose.Cells.Drawing.ActiveXControls.ComboBoxActiveXControl combo = ws.Shapes[0].ActiveXControl as Aspose.Cells.Drawing.ActiveXControls.ComboBoxActiveXControl;
combo.Value = "Y";
```

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: why I did not see "ask a question" in your company forum?

Comment: in fact, I use `Cells.InsertRow(rowindex);`  to get a new row, but I want to make it a choice type.

Comment: let me have a try

Comment: ok. i directly put "Y" and it seems good!

Comment: ok that's good.

Comment: and regarding "ask a question", it is mentioned here (https://about.aspose.com/contact/).